# Select rows having the same features than others

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, group-by

I've the following table with 3 columns: Id, FeatureName and Value:

```
Id  FeatureName  Value
--  -----------  -----
1   AAA          10
1   ABB          12
1   BBB          12
2   AAA          15
2   ABB          12
2   ACD           7
3   AAA          10
3   ABB          12
3   CCC          12
.............
```

Each Id has different features and each Feature has a value for that Id.

I need to write a query which gives me the Ids that have exactly the same features and values than a given one, but only taking into account those whose name starts with 'A'. For example, in the top table, I can use that query to search for all the Ids that have the same features. For example, features with values where Id=1 would result Id=3 with same features starting with 'A' and same values for these features.

I found a couple of different ways to do this, but all of them go very slow when the table has lots of rows (more than hundred of thousands)

The way I obtain the best performance is using the next query:

```
select a2.Id 
from (select a.FeatureName, a.Value
      from Table1 a
      where a.Id = 1) a1,      
     (select a.Id, a.FeatureName, a.Value        
      from Table1 a  
      where  a.FeatureName like 'A%') a2 
where a1.FeatureName = a2.FeatureName
and a1.value = a2.value
group by a2.Id
having count(*) = 2

intersect

select a.Id
from Table1 a 
where a.FeatureName like 'A%'  
group by a.Id 
having count(*)= 2
```

where @nFeatures is the number of features starting by 'A' in Id=1. I counted them before calling this query. I make the intersection to avoid results that have the same parameters than Id=1 but also some others whose name starts with 'A'.

I think that the slowest part is the second subquery:

```
select a.Id, a.FeaureName, a.Value        
from MyTable a  
where  a.FeatureName = 'A%'
```

but I don't know how to make it faster. Maybe I will have to play with the indexes.

Any idea of how could I write a fast query for this purpose?

Comment: _" in the top table, I can use that query"_ _what_ query?

Comment: `I found a couple of different ways to do this`. Well, can we see those queries?

Comment: I add an example of the query which gives me the best performance. I also tried to do it generating a dynamic query with all the names of the features, and it work quite well if the number of different features is quite small, but it slows a lot if there are lots of different features.

Answer (score 1):

So you want all rows where the combination of `FeatureName` and `Value` is not unique? You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM dbo.Table1 t
WHERE t.FeatureName LIKE 'A%'
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table1 t2
           WHERE t.Id <> t2.ID
           AND   t.FeatureName = t2.FeatureName
           AND   t.Value       = t2.Value)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3872b0/12/0)</kbd>

> how could I write a fast query for this purpose?

If it's not fast enough create an index on FeatureName + Value.

Comment: Except, I think he wants a match of all features/values, nothing missing/no extras.

Comment: I need the Ids that have exactly the same feature/value pairs than the Id=1, but taking into account only the features starting with 'A' and ignoring the others.

Comment: @Antuan: Then use `WHERE t.FeatureName LIKE 'A%'`. Edited my answer accordingly. However, this query doesn't check if there is another row  in an ID-Group with a `FeatureName`/`Value` combination that does not exist in the other ID-Group or vice-versa. So what @Clockwork-Muse mentioned (i guess).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Your query returns all the records that any of the feature/value pairs of a given one, but I need the Id numbers which **have exactly the same** feature/value pairs than a given one, no more no less, but only taking into account those records whose FeatureName estras with 'A'

Comment: @Antuan: you haven't even shown a desired result and sample data which covers all edge cases. Maybe you want something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3872b0/16/0 (which checks also the count)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to eliminate the join with MyTable again to select the data for the ID's that have matching FeatureName and Value values. Here's the query:

```
with joined_set as
(
    SELECT
    mt1.*, mt2.id as mt2_id, mt2.featurename as mt2_FeatureName, mt2.value as mt2_value
    from
    (
        select *
        from mytable
        where featurename like 'A%'
    ) mt1
    left join
    (
        select *
        from mytable
        where featurename like 'A%'
    ) mt2
    on mt2.id <> mt1.id and mt2.FeatureName = mt1.featurename and mt2.value = mt1.value
)
select distinct id
from joined_set
where id not in 
    (select id 
        from joined_set 
        group by id 
        having SUM(
                CASE 
                    WHEN mt2_id is null THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
                ) <> 0
    );
```

Here is the <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f78fb/4)</kbd> demo. It has an extra condition in the inline view mt2, to perform this search only for id = 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little dense this morning, I'm not sure if you wanted just the ID's or... 
Here's my take on it... 
You could probably move the where FeatureName like 'A%' into the inner query to filter the data on the initial table scan.

```
with dupFeatures (FeatureName, Value, dupCount)
as
(
select FeatureName, Value, count(*) as dupCount from MyTable
group by FeatureName, Value
having count(*) > 1
)
select MyTable.Id, dupFeatures.FeatureName,dupFeatures.Value
from dupFeatures
join MyTable on (MyTable.FeatureName = dupFeatures.FeatureName and
                 MyTable.Value = dupFeatures.Value )
where dupFeatures.FeatureName like 'A%'                 
order by FeatureName, Value, Id
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution is

```
With Rows As (
select id
     , FeatureName
     , Value
     , rows = Count(id) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
FROM   test
WHERE  FeatureName LIKE 'A%')
SELECT a.id aID, b.id bID
FROM   Rows a
       INNER JOIN Rows b ON a.id < b.id and a.FeatureName = b.FeatureName 
             and a.rows = b.rows
GROUP BY a.id, b.id
ORDER BY a.id, b.id
```

to limit the solution to a group just add a WHERE condition on the main query for a.ID. The CTE is needed to get the correct number of rows for each id

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4dd31/9) demo, in the demo I changed little the test data to have a another couple of ID with only one of the FeatureName of 1 and 3